# Image and Text not going at a time through android messaging

Tags: android, android-intent, messaging

Tried with below code and its going image but not text through messaging and it works fine with email, whatsapp. can any one suggest me how to do it

```
Uri shareImageUri = saveBitmapImage(result);
                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareImageUri);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"byeeeeeeeeeeee");

                emailIntent.setType("image/png");
                mActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String fileName = "image_file_name.jpg";//Name of an image
String externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String myDir = externalStorageDirectory + "/saved_images/"; // the file will be in saved_images
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///" + myDir + fileName);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/html");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Mail");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Launcher");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image and Text"));
```

or

```
File filePath = getFileStreamPath("share_image.jpg");  //optional //internal storage
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
     shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share content");
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));  //optional//use this when you want to send an image
     shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
     shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share"));
```